# How to push parent object from jQuery.ajax success statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, oop

I have one function which contains child functions and objects:

```
//API load function
var apiDataLoader = function ()     {

    // Set default settings
    this.apiSeason = '7924';
    this.apiMatchDay = '30';
    this.apiType = 'gamelist';
    this.apiLink = 'http://example.com/';
    this.apiLinkData = {
        app: this.apiType,
        season_num: this.apiSeason,
        match_day: this.apiMatchDay
    }
    this.apiData = new Object;


    //load API
    apiDataLoader.prototype.load = function()       {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.apiLink,
            data: this.apiLinkData,
            success: function(data) {
                apiDataLoader.apiData = data; //this is not working
                // I need to push somehow responce data to 'apiDataLoader.apiData' object
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see in my code, I'm trying to push `$.ajax` response to parent function object element named: `apidataLoader.apiData`, but i can't achieve this.

Any ideas?

**P.S: response in `data` value is `JSON` object.**

Comment: how do you use `apiDataLoader` ?   with `new`(something like that: `var loader = new apiDataLoader()`) and then a `loader.load()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is right now you are creating a new property on the constructor `apiDataLoader`, not the  current instance. Here's one way to do it:

```
$.ajax({
    url: this.apiLink,
    data: this.apiLinkData,
    dataType: 'json', //will automatically parse the response as JSON
    success: function(data) {
        this.apiData = data;
    },
    context: this //sets the context object to the current instance in the callback
});
```

Also, please note that your prototype functions should be declared outside the constructor, otherwise there's no advantage in using the prototype since the functions are redeclared for each newly created instances. Additionnaly, constructors starts with an upper-case letter as a convention in JS and you should probably follow it.

```
function ApiDataLoader() {
    //...
}

ApiDataLoader.prototype = {
    constructor: ApiDataLoader,
    load: function () {
        //...
    }
};
```

Comment: This is more smooth and nice solution right from `jQuery.ajax` settings. Thanks

Comment: @zur4ik If you are wondering why we need to set the `constructor` property of the `prototype`, it's because with the implementation I shown, we replace the whole `prototype` to define it as an object literal. It has the advantage of being less verbose, however the initial `prototype` object had a `constructor` property pointing to the correct function while now, the newly created object will have it's constructor property point to `Object`. That's why we are fixing it. You do not need to fix it if you are never using `this.constructor`.

Comment: I got this, but have another question:

what difference is between object function: 

`ApiDataLoader.prototype.load = function() `

and


`function ApiDataLoader() {
    //...
    this.load = function() {
       //..
    }

}`

Comment: is there any performance matter? if not, why I need to use prototype when I can describe sub-function with: `this.functionName = function() {} ` ?

Comment: @zur4ik Using the `prototype` takes less memory since all functions are shared between instances. The construction process will also be faster since you do not have to redefine every functions each time `new ApiDataLoader` is called, unlike using [privileged methods](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html).

Comment: @plax now I see the difference. Thanks for tips.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
apiDataLoader.prototype.load = function()       {
        var self = this; //Store the current object to avoid `this` problem in javascript.
        $.ajax({
            url: this.apiLink,
            data: this.apiLinkData,
            success: function(data) {
                self.apiData = data; //assign value
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: `self=this` is so nice and simple solution for that! Thanks man! this worked.

Comment: @zur4ik This also works and is a great solution, however I would recommend using another variable name like `me` or `that` since `self`  [already exists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.self).

Comment: @plalx: I define it as a local variable, should not collide with `window.self`.

Comment: @KhanhTO No, it cannot collide, but it will **shadow it**. It doesn't matter in this case but could in general (think of using this approach at a module level), some might try to use `self` later and it will not point to what they expect.

Answer (score 1):

Since `load()` is defined on the prototype of `apiDataLoader`, it will receive an instance of `apiDataLoader` as a context when it is called, in others words, the `this` keyword inside `load()` will point to the instance of `apiDataLoader` on which it is called, so you need to change the code to this one:

```
apiDataLoader.prototype.load = function()       {

    var that = this; // this is the instance of apiDataLoader on which this method is called
    $.ajax({
        url: this.apiLink,
        data: this.apiLinkData,
        success: function(data) {
            that.apiData = data; //assign value
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `this` in the `success` callback is not `apiDataLoader`.

Comment: @t.niese Sorry, a mistake of rush, will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the `apiData` property of the current object using `this`, however you'll need to cache it outside of the `$.ajax` success handler as the scope of `this` in that function will be different. Try this:

```
apiDataLoader.prototype.load = function() {
    var _this = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: this.apiLink,
        data: this.apiLinkData,
        success: function(data) {
            _this.apiData = data;
        }
    });
}
```